# Symbolic Link with Existing Directory

Tags: symlink

If I already has a directory (A) with existing contents and another directory (B), how do I symbolic link such that the two directory's content merge.

```
   eg.   A 
           -> folderA1/
           -> a.bin
           -> b.bin (from B folder)
           -> c.bin (from B folder)
         B 
           -> b.bin
           -> c.bin
```

Comment: Checkout this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423320/can-i-symlink-multiple-directories-into-one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a script that runs trough directory B that creates a link for every file in directory A. But, if you want to *merge* the two folders, I recommend using an **overlay filesystem** such as [aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs). I use it myself for such a task.

Use the following mount command (You may have to install the tools to manage aufs):

```
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/path/to/dirA/=rw:/path/to/dirB/=ro none /path/to/mountpoint
```

**Explanation** of the mount command:

- `-t aufs`: Sets the filesystem type to aufs
- `dirs=/path/to/dirA/=rw:/path/to/dirB/=ro`: those are the directories you want to merge, sepatated by a `:`. It can also be a third directory if you want. Note that `dirA` is used as readwrite (`rw`) folder and `dirB` as readonly (`ro`). That means when you write into that mountpoint the filesystem writes into `dirA`, not `dirB`. There are lots of [options](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs.html), how the underlaying filesystem should behave in case of read or write. I recommend to see through the manual page.
- `none`: this is the device. Because it's a pseudo filesystem, there is no device.
- `/path/to/mountpoint`: the path where you want to mount the filesystem.

Comment: so its an filesystem on top of the unix default filesystem that perform the union.

Comment: Yes it's overlaid. The underlying filesystems could be everything. From a `tmpfs` over `nfs` to an usbfilesystem.